# Появление стороннего цвета при выборе пункта bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-drawable

Пытаюсь сделать выделение цветом отдельного выбранного елемента в bottomNavigationView как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472528/change-background-colour-of-area-behind-selected-item-in-android-bottom-navigati) вопросе. Для этого сделал файл в папке drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/un_checked" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

подключаю его в разметке:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />
```

в итоге не активированный пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот активированный пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в итоге у меня возник вполне закономерный вопрос - откуда взялся этот сиреневый цвет если я его вообще никак не использовал?

### UPDATE

вот что получается после правки разметки:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/checked"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />
```

но с такой разметкой приложение падает:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

этого цвета вообще нигде нет в проекте. Он нигде не упоминается.

Comment: Скорее всего это `colorAccent` из стилей.

Comment: А в `res/values/colors.xml` такой цвет есть?

Comment: Очень странно. Попробуйте убрать `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"` - это выглядит лишним. Может, в этом дело)

Comment: В ответе по ссылке не так как у вас - там нет состояния `android:state_checked="false"` и нет атрибутов, которые я выше предложил удалить

Comment: Угу... Наверное эти параметры таки нужны в разметке... Попробуйте им какой-то цвет задать, например белый вместо вашего селектора: `        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"`. И вы не сказали поменяли ли сам селектор. По примеру из ссылки на en-SO, которую вы удалили, не было `android:state_checked="false"`, а у вас есть и таким образом нет дефолтного состояния в селекторе.

Comment: Оно должно работать как-то так: 1. В ресурсе меню указываете иконку и текст. 2. В разметке указываете цвет фона. Если он должен меняться - указываете в селекторе цвет дефолтный и для выбранного состояния. У вас это сделано неправильно и вы игнорируете мои предложения это исправить. 3. В разметке указываете цвет иконке. Это тоже можно селектором делать по тем же правилам что и в п2. 4. Тоже самое что и п 2 и п3 для текста. Вывод - разберитесь с селектором как я выше описал - должно помочь.

Comment: с селектором я разобрался сразу же после того как вы мне об этом сказали)) я выполнил - 1 пункт, дальше в разметке получается такой прикол - когда я ставлю стандартный один цвет, то все работает хорошо, а когда я ставлю селекторный цвет, то приложение падает с вышеуказанной ошибкой, с цветом иконок проблем нет и с текстом тоже

Comment: Тогда об этом хорошо бы в вопросе написать чтобы никого не путать) Вы в селекторе, кажется, не цвет, но иконку ставите. Попробуйте таки цвет ставить как и было в примере по удалённой вами (и не добавленной в вопрос) ссылке. `<item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_checked="true"/>  <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих мучений, и блогодаря помощи @ЮрийСПб, я смог добиться того что мне нужно. Чтобы сделать выделение цветом, нужно в папке res добавить директорию color и в ней добавить xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
</selector>
```

этот файл будет отвечать за выделение выбранного элемента изменением фона выбранного элемента. Дальше, нужно в папке drawable добавить файл который будет отвечать за изменение цвета текста и иконки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#3f3f3f" />
</selector>
```

и в конце нужно это все подключить в разметке к вашему bottomNavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text"
        app:menu="@menu/main_bottom_nav_menu" />
```

и вот итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще раз спасибо @ЮрийСПб за что направил в нужную сторону. Может кому пригодится.